# Escaping CSS digits, 0 is removed from CSS aggregated files

Tags: theming, css-js-aggregation

The following HTML markup won't work on a production site.

```html
<div class="iconleft 109">TEXT</div>
```

This is the code in the custom.css file.

```css
.iconleft.\31 09,
.iconleft.\31 12,
.iconleft.\31 10,
.iconleft.\31 11,
.iconleft.\31 20 {
  background: #B0CD00;
}
```

`.iconleft.\31 09` works on localhost with xampp and no aggregation. On the production site, where Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation is activated, it wont work for 109.

In the aggregated CSS file, I see `.iconleft.\31 9` as CSS class. It seems that 0 has been removed.

Do you have any hint?

Comment: This is neither valid HTML nor valid CSS. Apart from the missing opening quote at the class attribute, a CSS identifier (such as a class name or an ID) must not start with a number.

Comment: @Hudri I thought the same thing and commented as much before digging - turns out we’re wrong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882839/what-does-container-31-25-25-mean-in-css

Comment: Holy sh**, this is by far the weirdest, yet valid code I've seen for a long time o_O - I highly doubt any CSS preprocessor can handle that correctly out of the box. By the link you provided, try providing exactly 6 hexadecimal digits (for the leading hex-encoded char) instead of ending with a space, e.g. `.iconleft.\00003109` instead of `.iconleft.\31 09`

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is valid.

Anyway due to lack of time i decided to ad an "id" to the class. So the html is now

```
<div class="iconleft id-{{ child_id }}">Text</div>
```

And the css

```
.iconleft.id-109,
.iconleft.id-112,
.iconleft.id-110,
.iconleft.id-111,
.iconleft.id-120 {
  background: #B0CD00;
}
```

This is working for me.

But if somebody knows why aggregation removes the "0" please let me know.